# Change Angularjs 1.3.0 syntax - Conflicting with Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using Angularjs as a front-end framework and using Laravel 4 as a back-end framework. But, I've got this annoying conflict between Angularjs and blade's syntax `{{}}` so I would like to know how to change Angularjs syntax, because changing blade's is no option for me!

I've been making some diggings on stackoverflow and other websites but all the solutions I have tried didn't work out for me.

I have found answers like this one but they all didn't work out for me:

```
  myModule.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Am I mistaking something or this code is not operating under Angularjs 1.3.0?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: This should work, you can check it out [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

Comment: it seems like I'm mistaking something, because I have already checked this page.
What I actually did (and do), I copy/past the code from the documentation under my `main.js` but it doesn't work. Would you please help with any suggestions?

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8euxcjf3/); it suggests the code above works. Maybe you could provide one that doesn't or, with this fiddle as starting point find a solution. Good luck anyway! Also check the obvious, that the code above actually *runs*...

Comment: I fixed the problem from the link you have provided to the documentation. I only had to change the position of `ng-app="app"` and put the code from the documentation at the very bottom of the page right before `</body>`